# Signing in as admin on behalf of others with Email/Password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase V3, when an user has created an account using Email/Password, can I as the admin sign in on behalf of it's account, without knowing the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the user's uid, you can use custom auth to sign-in to that user's account. I think the better way, if you are saving that user's data using real time database, is to grant yourself admin privileges and update the rules appropriately to allow yourself permission to edit that account's data.